# Not able to run nodemon (SyntaxError: Unexpected token) on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

command I am running : nodemon server.js,
error I am getting :

```
nodemon server.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:58
            } catch {
                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js:15:3)
```

I tried various ways of installing nodemon on Ubuntu but still getting exact same error every time I run.

Comment: What is your `nodejs` version ?

Comment: @yousoumar v8.10.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason could be your node.js installation is outdated.
You should upgrade to the recent version of node.js
You can check the version with:

```
node -v
```

If the version is recent, then you should try installing `nodemon` globally with this command

```
# using npm:
npm install -g nodemon 

# or using yarn: 
yarn global add nodemon
```

If you are stuck in an old version of node.js then do this:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

Then go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and remove any node list if you have. Then do a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Check for any `.npm` or `.node` folder in your home folder and delete those.

If you type

```
which node
```

you can see the location of the node. Try `which nodejs` and `which npm` too.

Then do a fresh installation like this

```
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
nano nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Comment: Yes version was the issue. Updated to recent version and it worked